# node, app.get not found, using parametr

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, url, routes

I'm trying to get this route: GET /exercisesadd?id=google-oauth2%7C10385839303782

FrontEnd:

```
getResults: function(){
  console.log(this.state.profile.user_id)
  return axios.get('/exercisesadd', {
    params: {
      id: this.state.profile.user_id
    }
  })
  .then(function(response){      
    return response;
  });
}
```

Server has:

```
app.get('/exercisesadd/:id', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you are making the query request but your server don't have the route for the query request.

When you make  GET `/exercisesadd?id=google-oauth2%7C10385839303782` in your server you must have the route with `/exercisesadd?id`, you only have the route for params

try this and view the console

```
app.get('/exercisesadd/:id?', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Query', req.query, 'Params', req.params)
  res.send(req.params);
});
```

GET `localhost:3000/exercisesadd?id=google-oauth2%7C10385839303782`
where `req.query` will give you `{ id: 'google-oauth2|10385839303782' }`

AND

GET `localhost:3000/exercisesadd/13134124252`
where `req.params` will give you `{ id: '13134124252' }`